# Android Studio aapt.exe missing error message after importing cordova project

Tags: java, android

Error:Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.

> aapt is missing on 'C:\Users\rv498\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe'

Hello, I have done importing cordova project to Android Studio before with no problems.  My android studio is the latest stable version because I reinstalled it today (3/17/17).  Please help  thanks.

BTW, the reason I started to import to Android Studio from Cordova is because I was starting get message about gradle wrapper missing from cordova CLI.  I suspect this is SDK Manager issue and I went there but after few attempts, nothing really progressed.

Answer (score 1):

-I had same issue so i opened C:\Users\Sheriff\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.2
-i saw aapt2.exe then i changed it to aapt.exe

-Closed my project on the android studio then opened it back it was working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution

- check if `aapt.exe` is in fact missing  `C:\Users\rv498\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\`
- it's there? echeck perms, check `%PATH%`
- it is not there? find where it is. Copy it to the location above

of check why it looks for it in that place. Is there's any config file that got the above path? If so, edit it.

Answer (score 0):

`aapt.exe` file moved to the latest sdk build tools folder

I just found `aapt.exe` file in my latest Android-SDK folder (*Android_SDK\build-tools\28.0.3*) 

You can check your latest sdk build-tools folder
or
You can search on total Android SDK folder by file name